# How to view device LAN address with Xamarin Android app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm writing an app in Xamarin Android, that is supposed to print the LAN address of the device using the app.

Here is what I try:

```
using System;
using Android.OS;
using Android.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Net.Wifi;
using Android.Content;
using Java.Util;
using Java.Net;

namespace checks
{
[Activity(Label = "checks", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        Button dataButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.connectionDataButton);
        dataButton.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {            
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
            var d = wifiManager.DhcpInfo;
            Console.WriteLine("My IP IS: {0}",d.IpAddress);
        };

    }
}
}
```

I keep getting: MY IP IS: 0

Can anybody tell  me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if any wifi network is available first, if not, DhcpInfo.ipAdress returns 0.

Comment: do you know why using the same code, d.Netmask returns 0 even with a wifi connection?

Comment: You could read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45697233/xamarin-android-dhcpinfo-netmask-returns-0